Regex pattern match is not working with Google Cloud Armor Security Policy
I am trying to implement rate limiting for GET and POST for the same API call. The only difference in both the request is extra ID we are passing with POST.
GET  /rest/v1/add 
POST /rest/v1/add/some-alpha-numeric-id-001

Since these are two separate request so I am trying to implement rate limiting for both.
    #To match GET Request 
    match {
      expr {
        expression = <<EOT
request.path.matches(R"\/v1\/add$")
EOT
      }
    }

    #To match POST request
    match {
      expr {
        expression = <<EOT
request.path.matches(R"\/vi\/add\/.+")
EOT
      }
    }

Do you have any suggestions to implement the rate limiting for both GET and POST request?
If I am using only request.path.matches("/v1/add") then it will obviously apply on both the but I am trying to setup different threshold for both request.
PS: I got to know about RAW pattern matching from here.
Regex Pattern Match Reference: https://regex101.com/r/zo3W5z/1

Why are you using regex when the path is a constant that can be matched using ==?

@Bohemian, The path is same for GET and POST, except there is ID adding in post after /add/. If we are configuring rule to match /v1/add then it's matching for POST and GET request. I was not aware we can use request.method to match the request type as @marcin suggested below.

But request.path.matches(R"\/v1\/add$" can just be request.path == "/v1/add" no? Also, you don't need to escape slashes, which have no special meaning in regex.

First, this smells a bit
GET  /rest/v1/add 
POST /rest/vi/add/

as your POST match rule mentions /vi/add/.+ when it seems it rather should be /v1/add/.+ if you are following a consistent versioning scheme (rest of my answer assumes this is a typo to be corrected).
Next, to the main point - you'll need to set up separate rate limiting rules that distinguish between these requests using regexp and additional conditions to differentiate by HTTP method, like this:
# Rate limiting for GET
match {
  expr {
    expression = <<EOT
request.method == "GET" && request.path.matches(R"\/v1\/add$")
EOT
  }
}

# Rate limiting for POST
match {
  expr {
    expression = <<EOT
request.method == "POST" && request.path.matches(R"\/v1\/add\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+")
EOT
  }
}


Thanks for your answer and yes there was typo in question.
I was not aware we can check request type using request.method.
